# What is causing incorrect view sizing for UIViewController's view?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, frame

My view controller's view is reporting itself to be `460` (on 3.5" screen). [480 - 20 = 460]

The view should really be `367` on account of the tabBar at the bottom (49) and navigationBar (44) and status bar (20) at the top. [480 - 20 - 44 - 49 = 367]

Why is the view's frame being calculated wrong??

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your view is not being resized to "fit" and account for your tabBar and navigationBar views. Have you set the autoresizing properties of your view? If not, check out the related [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5) for more info.